# Java Coding - Multiple Variables to create answer variable

Tags: java

Needing a guidance moment from the coding gods on how I could go about making my code do what I need it to.

**So the situation is:** 
I need to tell the program to run the calculation of the ticket price times the number of tickets purchased. Seems easy? **BUT** - There are three variables pre-luding to this.

See below:

```
    int TicketType = 0;
    double ChildTicket = 18.00;
    double AdultTicket = 36.00;
    double SeniorTicket = 32.50;
    int TicketQuantity = 0;
    double TotalCost = ?
```

Essentially - What i need to have happen from a Psuedocode level to make this easier:

```
Compute TotalCost = Result of ticket type (ChildTicket,AdultTicket or SeniorTicket) * TicketQuantity
```

Any help would be amazing! :)

Comment: *"Needing a guidance moment from the coding gods ..."* - Sorry, the gods are sleeping.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `switch` statement to find out the `TicketType` (Child, Adult, Senior) and thus the `price` of a single ticket:

```
double price;
switch(TicketType){
    case 1:
        price = ChildTicket;
        break;
    case 2:
        price = AdultTicket;
        break;
    case 3:
        price = SeniorTicket;
        break;   
    default:
        // use default value for price or throw an error
}
```

And then multiply that `price` with the `TicketQuantity` to get the `TotalCost`:

```
double TotalCost = price * TicketQuantity;
```

> **NOTE:** Java naming conventions says, that variables should always start with a lowerCase letter, so instead of `TotalCost` prefer `totalCost` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can store your variables as values into an array of doubles, then you can access to the value by using the index that is in the TicketType. Just like this:

```
int TicketType = 0;
double ticketsValues[] = [18.00,32.00,32.50]; //The first position is ChildTicket, the 2nd AdultTicket and so..
int TicketQuantity = 0;
double TotalCost = ticketsValue[TicketType] * TicketQuantity;//Here you access to the value depending on the TicketType.
```

Comment: This will throw an error, when `TicketType` is not an appropriate index, but else, an elegant solution

Comment: @Lino It's equal to your default case throwing an exception :) However it could be more specific than an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Like a `NoSuchTicketTypeException`.

Comment: @L.Spillner That's what I mean, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is almost always something that should not occur, it's more a debugging thing than something one should rely on in production

Answer (score 1):

Use Enum for it, something like that :

```
public enum TicketType {
ADULT(36), CHILD(18), SENIOR(32,50);

private final int cost;
TicketType(int cost) { this.cost = cost; }
public int getValue() { return cost; }
```

}

```
public int getTotalPrice(TicektType tp, int quantity){
return tp.getValue() * quantity;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the Advice Everyone. I actually came up with my own work around for the issue (and had a moment of dumbness because I forgot to initialize 3 more variables that were missing for the equation :P)

Comment: `id` that becomes `value` in the getter. I think that you was the victim of an unfortunate copy paste. It is a pity because your overall idea is fine.

Comment: Yeap, I've just realized this. Now should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an enum with a constructor like

```
public enum Ticket{
    SENIOR(7.0), ADULT(10.0), CHILD(3.0);

    Ticket(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private final double price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this.

I would recommend to create an `Enum` for the different type of tickets.

```
public enum TicketType {
    SENIOR(32.50D),
    ADULT(36.00D),
    CHILD(18.00D);

    private final double price;

    TicketType(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public double getCalculatedPrice(int ticketAmount) {
        return price * ticketAmount;
    }
}
```

Instead of that you can also try this way

```
int ticketType = 0; //change
double[] prices = {32.50D, 36.00D, 18.00D}; //Senior, Adult, Child
int ticketQuantity = 0; //change
int totalCost = prices[ticketType] * ticketQuantity;
```

Some additions to that you should check if the `ticketType` isn't bigger or less than the `prices` size to avoid a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You also should check if the quantity isn't less than zero.

Answer (score 1):

As the age groups (senior, adult, child) shouldn't change it's appropriate to define an enum (`TicketType`) for like the other answers suggest. But since the prices may change I wouldn't hard code them in the enum iself. I suggest to use a map:

```
Map<TicketType, Double> prices = new EnumMap<>(TicketType.class);
prices.put(TicketType.CHILD, ChildTicket);
prices.put(TicketType.ADULT, AdultTicket);
prices.put(TicketType.SENIOR, SeniorTicket);
```

The map could be filled with prices read from a datasource and updated everytime a price changes.

Getting the price for an adult for example is just calling:

```
double adultPrice = prices.get(TicketType.ADULT);
```

or more general:

```
public double getPriceFor(TicketType type) {
    return prices.get(type) ;
}
```

To answer the last part of your question. The total cost can be calculated then as follows:

```
public double getTotalCost(int children, int adults, int seniors) {
    return getPriceFor(TicketType.CHILD) * children +
            getPriceFor(TicketType.ADULT) * adults+
            getPriceFor(TicketType.SENIOR) * seniors;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentionning that prices should really come from an external data source (e.g. config file or DB). However I disagree with ticket categories being unlikely to change. Soon enough someone would wish for a `Student`, `Employee` or `SpecialBonusCardOwner` category - in real software, categories should be configurable as well.

Comment: @Hulk I cannot deny it. There are cases which will distinguish more groups. And maybe there will be a need for more/different groups in the future. I was assuming this is not as likely as changing prices. But this depends on the domain and the customer's requirements. Anyway both ways are shown. The OP can decide which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

And here is what I ended up doing. Step 1 added additional options in the initialization

```
    double Option1 = ChildTicket;
    double Option2 = AdultTicket;
    double Option3 = SeniorTicket;
```

THEN - In the actual code where it required the information and results, created a miniseries of if statements to correlate to the correct option:

```
    if (TicketType == 1) {
         System.out.println ("Child tickets are $18.00,How many would you like to purchase?"); 
         TicketQuantity =input.nextInt();
         TotalCost = Option1 * TicketQuantity;
         System.out.println ("Total Cost of tickets = $" + (TotalCost));
         System.out.println ("Press 1 to confirm");
         Confirmation = input.nextInt();
```

Not bad for a beginner